# Need a resource to find out about latest attack activity?

Tags: network-monitoring, malware

Thought about this seeing another question pop up about a user agent string showing up in the poster's logs; is there a site for sysadmins to go to for finding the latest information about signatures/tell tale signs of attacks currently running wild on the network? I know google-fu can help with stringing together evidence until I find things like "I'm seeing this on my network" or "this is in my log files..." but if a worm or malware attack is fairly new, searching typical virus databases from vendors may not be up to date (plus they can put a proprietary spin on things).

Is there a good central site for sysadmins to refer to when they see a sudden uptick in particular ports being probed or a particular string showing up in a scan or unusual activity in their internal network?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A couple of resources off the top of my head:

- [SANS Storm Center](http://isc.sans.edu/index.html)
- [SANS Site](http://www.sans.edu)
- [McAfee Threat Center](http://www.mcafee.com/us/threat_center/default.asp)
- [Symantec ThreatCon](http://www.symantec.com/security_response/threatcon/index.jsp)

Answer (score 1):

[**US-CERT**](http://www.us-cert.gov/nav/t01/) is another (link points to the area for technical folk)